# Save machine state to disk in Xen

Tags: hibernate, xen

After numerous issues and problems with Linux kernel committing the state to disk (aka STD/Hibernate) I decided to resort to VM instead.

I wish to know if it's possible to commit the entire state of dom0 to disk? And then resume from that state at a later time.

Comment: I don’t see how that would make any difference at all. Instead, you should focus on solving your hibernation problems.

Comment: What full of silly presumptions. Answer the specific question or don't answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

In the host environment, enter

```
xm save ID state-file
```

where `ID` is the virtual machine ID you want to save, and `state-file` is the name you specify for the memory state file.

To resume enter

```
xm restore state-file
```

where state-file is the previously saved memory state file.

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20210923140807/https://documentation.suse.com/sles/11-SP4/html/SLES-all/cha-xen-save.html